# tool for Cyrillic text recognition

Tags: text-processing, tools, cyrillic

Are there any tools to recognize cyrillic text from image.?
it seems that OCR works only with latin letters.

Comment: Have you tried http://www.free-ocr.com/ ?

Comment: @Android Dev, finally i got my text with that (and also i have applied the occam's razor). thank you.

Comment: also i have tried `tesseract`, but effect was not so bright, as with free-orc. possibly  it has many options to configure recognition, but my time is limited for now.